# Using middleware crashes when accessing a route

Tags: node.js

I was wondering why my router "/posts" is not running or it's just stuck loading its page when I include a middleware of app.use()

```
const express = require('express');
//Initialize Express
const app = express();

//Middleware
//When I comment this app.use line of code I can access the /posts router but when I left it uncommented 
//My localhost sometimes error and keeps on loading 
app.use('/posts',()=>{
    console.log(' middleware');
});

//Ability to create routes
//ROUTES
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send('We are on Home page');    
});

app.get("/posts", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Welcome back user Ice");
});

//Start Listening to our Server
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: you don't call `next`. See the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application).

Comment: please read article from express official site here  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: I'm just following a tutorial from youtube. While trying things out I can't seem to follow him because of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, you're stuck at

```
app.use('/posts',()=>{
    console.log(' middleware');
    // You should either call next() here or respond to the HTTP here
})
```

To understand this, you need to get the concept of middleware in express.

You can imagine middleware like a list of `function` that a HTTP call should go through, depending on how you arrange it. All middleware registered with express will have access to  request object `req`, the response object `res`, and the `next` middleware function. Among the best benefits of middleware pattern is it avoids coupling the sender of a request to the receiver by giving more than one `function` a chance to handle the request. Both the receiver and the sender have no explicit knowledge of each other.

Types of express middleware

- Application level middleware `app.use`
- Router level middleware `router.use`
- Built-in middleware
  `express.static`,`express.json`,`express.urlencoded`
- Error handling middleware `app.use(err,req,res,next)`
- Thirdparty middleware `bodyparser`,`cookieparser`

To better understand why ur code is stucked, lets look at your code again.

```
const express = require('express');
//Initialize Express
const app = express();

//Middleware
// You registered an application level middleware here, which its route is 
// reached via http://localhost:3000/posts
// If you are going to respond here, you should first pass a `req` & `res` 
// as a variable to the callback. Then you can just `res.json` `res.send` 

// If you want to run some pre-processing of the or checks on the request before
// passing to other middleware, then you should call `next()` when you are done with
// the logic

app.use('/posts',()=>{
    console.log(' middleware');
});

//Ability to create routes
//ROUTES
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send('We are on Home page');    
});

app.get("/posts", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Welcome back user Ice");
});

//Start Listening to our Server
app.listen(3000);
```

If you opt for middleware case (per your question), you need to do this

```
app.use('/posts',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(' middleware');
    next()  // This pass the control to the next middleware registered 
});
// Now the request will be passed to this middleware, and runs as you expected
app.get("/posts", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Welcome back user Ice");
});
```